# displaying data when table is null

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-xi, isnull

I have a data table of inventory locations and the items that are on hand in that location.  I have a separate data set of standard inventory items that are SUPPOSED to be in that location.  I have a third data set of global part information.  I can build  report to show the part information and quantity on hand for a location, but when I try to display what should be in that location, the report stops showing parts data for items which are in the location, but should not be.  The three data fields I am working with are:

```
{LOCITEMS.QTYONHAND} {STDITEMS.QUANTITY} {PARTS.PARTNBR}
```

In essence, I am trying to structure a report with the following format:

**Part Number**......**Description**.....**Qty On Hand**.....**Standard Qty**

When a part number is not included in the STDITEMS data set, it simply stops being displayed on the report.  I would like **Part Number**, **Description** and **Qty On Hand** to be displayed but leave the Standard Qty field blank.

Been racking my brain on this one, but I feel I am too new to Crystal to see the forest for the trees.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The description is a bit confused to me, but my long shot is that maybe you just need to use the link expert in crystal reports to change a link ther to a left outer join. If it is not the case, may you describe your schema and the relationships? Maybe post a sample of your data.

Comment: I just came across the Left Outer Join feature and am goign to try that.